Find the roots of the tropical polynomial
Consider the polynomial $3\odot x^3 \oplus (-1) \odot x^2 \oplus (-2) \odot x \oplus (-7) $ i want to find the zeros of that polynomial, from where $a \odot b= a+b$ and $a \oplus b= \max (a, b)$
It seems that the graph of this polynomial draws four lines in the plane, exactly the lines $y=3x+3$, $y=2x-1$, $y=x-2$, and the horizontal line $y=-7$, and we can given a factorization like
$$p(x)=3 \odot (x \oplus (-1-3)) \odot (x \oplus  (-2-1)) \odot (x \oplus (-7-2))$$
From here I can deduce something useful to find the roots, any help is appreciated!

Draw the four linear functions you mentioned, and color the maximum of the four. You can read the roots directly from the graph.

Isn’t this the graph of the factorization assuming the subtraction is ordinary arithmetic?

We assume associativity which is clearly valid.
We have $\left(3\odot x^3\right) \oplus \left(-1 \odot x^2\right) \oplus \left(-2 \odot x\right) \oplus \left(-7\right)$ and
$$3\odot x^3=x^3+3\\-1\odot x^2=x^2-1\\-2 \odot x=x-2$$
Note that because $a\oplus b=\max\{a,b\}$, each time that both $a$ and $b$ are real numbers has an evident "sum" but it is not the case when $a$ or $b$ are functions of $x$ because it depends on the values ​​of $x$. So
$$\left(3\odot x^3\right) \oplus \left(-1 \odot x^2\right)=\begin{cases}x^3+3\text { when }x^2-1\le x^3+3\iff x^3-x^2+4\ge0\\x^2-1\text { when } x^3+3\le x^2-1\iff x^3-x^2+4\le0\end{cases}$$
$$\left(-2 \odot x\right) \oplus \left(-7\right)=\begin{cases}-7\text { when }x-2\le-7\iff x\le-5\\ x-2\text { when }-7\le x-2\iff x\ge-5\end{cases}$$
Our $p(x)$ is the "sum" $\oplus$ of the two functions red and black on the attached figure, where $\color{red}{P=(-1.3146,0.7281)}$ and $Q=(-5,-7)$ where $x\approx-1.3146$ is an approximated value of the real solution of $x^3-x^2+4=0$

Because of the definition of the "sum" it is clear from the above figure that
$p(x)$ is the red function above defined so $p(x)\gt 0$ for all real $x$ and there are not zeros.

$x^3$ for a tropical polynomial generally refers to the linear function $3x$, not the actual function $x^3: \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$. Your curves aren't representattive of the actual function.
